# Microsoft graph api, deleting a subscription results in `404 Not Found`

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

By accident, I created a bunch of subscriptions for the same calendar, while I only need one.

Every time a calendar item is changed, I get like 40 callbacks (whoops!). I added some logic to simply request to cancel the subscription if it's not known in our database.

So, for instance, I receive this callback

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "subscriptionId": "007fbff0-aef1-413f-90b8-eb2097378101",
            "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2019-08-02T07:58:15+00:00",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I then send a DELETE request like so

`DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/007fbff0-aef1-413f-90b8-eb2097378101`

Since I just use the exact subscription ID received from the callback, I assume this subscription is known on the Graph servers, but I receive a `404 Not Found` response, and I continue to receive ~40 callbacks just like before.

This is the exact response I receive

```
A 404 Not Found response with the following body

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The object was not found.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "519154c3-795f-4dba-bf71-3abfb50e7a79",
      "date": "2019-08-01T09:50:44"
    }
  }
}
```

I use the PHP graph sdk, like so.

```
    public function removeSubscription(MsGraphSubscriptionToken $token): GraphResponse {
        // request is a small wrapper around the graph api
        return $this->request(self::ENDPOINT_SUBSCRIPTIONS . $token->getSubscriptionId(), "DELETE");
    }


...


    function request(string $url, string $type = "GET", $body = null, array $extraHeaders = null, int $retriesLeft = 3): GraphResponse {
        ...
        $request = $this->graph->createRequest($type, $url);

        $request->attachBody($body);
        if ($extraHeaders != null) {
            $request->addHeaders($extraHeaders);
        }

        ...
        $response = $request->execute();
    }
```

Comment: If you do a GET on subscriptions do you see the problematic subscriptions there? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @DarrelMiller Oddly enough, no not at all. Sending a GET to /subscriptions results in an array with ----0---- subscriptions, even though I am consistently getting callbacks. Very weird

Comment: @DarrelMiller I did some more research, and it's only getting odder. If I send the `GET /subscriptions` quickly after I set-up the connection, it shows me two subscriptions. If I then create an item in the Outlook calendar, I get callbacks from **8** distinct subscription-ids, the two "known" subscriptions are among these callbacks though.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Even odder, about 5 minutes later I performed the same `GET /subscriptions` request, and it listed 0 subscriptions again. Even though I'm still authenticated just the same, _and_ receiving callbacks precisely as before.

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you.  If I hear of any discussion relating to this I will reach out and try and keep you up to date.